# How to set auto.create.topics.enable as default config on AWS MSK cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

Our AWS MSK cluster is not automatically creating topics when a producer first publishes a message to the topic. This is surprising because the default behaviour according to https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs should have `auto.create.topics.enable = true`.

I have attempted to set this configuration on my brokers but I am unable because the config is `read-only` for dynamic updates.

```sh
$ kafka-configs --bootstrap-server $KAFKA_BROKER --entity-type brokers --entity-default --alter --add-config auto.create.topics.enable=true

Error while executing config command with args '--bootstrap-server $KAFKA_BROKER --entity-type brokers --entity-default --alter --add-config auto.create.topics.enable=true'
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidRequestException: Invalid config value for resource ConfigResource(type=BROKER, name=''): Cannot update these configs dynamically: Set(auto.create.topics.enable)
```

*note: I replaced our broker's IP with `$KAFKA_BROKER` in the output*

How can I configure my AWS MSK Kafka cluster to enable auto creation of topics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

You can now customise [MSK configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-configuration-properties.html):

> `auto.create.topics.enable`: Enables topic autocreation on the server.

Therefore, `auto.create.topics.enable=true` ([defaults to `false`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-default-configuration.html)) should now do the trick as usual.

---

Although `auto.create.topics.enable` normally defaults to `true`, this is not the case for AWS MSK. According to [these slides](https://aws-de-marketing.s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Field%20Marketing/Summit-Berlin-2019/Presentations/AWS_Summit_Berlin_2019_Feb26_DesigningLessSurrealArchitecturesWithApacheKafkaInAWS.pdf) presented in Berlin's AWS Kafka Summit this February, the following are the default configuration parameters for Amazon MSK:

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor 3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor 3
transaction.state.log.min.isr 2
auto.create.topics.enable False
default.replication.factor 3
min.insync.replicas 2
unclean.leader.election.enable True
auto.leader.rebalance.enable True
authorizer.class.name kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms 3000
log.retention.hours 168
```

Note that even Kafka docs mention that the [suggested production configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#prodconfig) should be set to `false`.

Comment: Please consider removing the older incorrect information from your answer.  I see no reason to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

Moving forward you can now set this parameter to `true` by [customizing the configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-configuration-properties.html), however it will stay `false` by default since that is the recommended production configuration.